# CTreeView MFC; what do the following mean?TVIF_HANDLE TVIF_IMAGE TVIF_PARAM TVIF_TEXT

Tags: c++, windows, mfc

If anyone can help me out with an explanation I'd be incredibly grateful. Also anyone who can explain what reflecting messaging notifications, such as ON_NOTIFY_RELECT, do would also make me very happy!

Thanks lots!
James

Answer (score 0):

ON_NOTIFY_RELECT is used when you want a subclass of your control to handle its own notifications.
Alternative is handing normal notifications by parent window

Comment: I was hoping for more practical explanation, but thanks anyway.

Comment: Do you mean - why is it needed in the first place? I prefer such reflected notifications when control is heavily customized to make sure it deals with own customizations, and is not relying on parent window. Encapsulation it is.

Answer (score 0):

These are flags used for struct TVITEM.

When calling SendMessage with the messages TVM_GETITEM or TVM_SETITEM, a pointer to a TVITEM struct has to be provided as last parameter (= LPARAM lParam).

With these flags you specify what values you want to get from the TreeView (for TVM_GETITEM) or what you have set in the struct and you want them to set in the TreeView (for TVM_SETITEM).